# Query improvements without UNION

Tags: postgresql, union

I have the following scenario. A `users` table, a `records` table and a `memberships` table.

A user can be associated to zero or more records either directly with the records table

```
records.user_id = users.id
```

or via a membership (the membership table contains `user_id` and `record_id`)

```
memberships.user_id = users.id
```

Let's assume I want to load all the records managed by the user. The query directly translates into

```
SELECT records.* FROM records WHERE records.user_id = ?
UNION
SELECT records.* FROM records
INNER JOIN memberships ON memberships.record_id = records.id
WHERE memberships.user_id = ?
```

Is there a way to combine these two queries into a single one without `UNION`?

I tried starting from:

```
SELECT records.* 
FROM records 
LEFT OUTER JOIN memberships ON memberships.record_id = records.id 
WHERE records.user_id = ? OR memberships.user_id = ?
```

But it also returns the records where the `JOIN` matches for other user memberships. Any hint?

Comment: Does the `LEFT` join query give you the correct result - but some rows are duplicated?

Comment: Yes, when the records had 1 ore more memberships, the same record was returned multiple times.

Comment: Can a user be associated via both ways (via `records.user_id` and via the memberships table)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `OR` with `EXISTS` or `IN`:
(the `IN` version only if the `memberships.record_id` column is not nullable)

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM records AS r
WHERE r.user_id = ?
   OR EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM memberships AS m
        WHERE m.record_id = r.id 
          AND m.user_id = ?
      ) ;

SELECT r.* 
FROM records AS r
WHERE r.user_id = ?
   OR r.id IN  
      ( SELECT m.record_id 
        FROM memberships AS m
        WHERE m.user_id = ?
      ) ;
```

This way you also do not get the duplicate rows of `records` that the join introduces (and then are get rid in the `UNION DISTINCT` part of your query.)

---

You could use the `LEFT` join query but you would have to either add `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` the primary key of the `records` table to avoid the duplicate rows:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM records  AS r
  LEFT OUTER JOIN memberships AS m
    ON m.record_id = r.id 
WHERE r.user_id = ? 
   OR m.user_id = ?
GROUP BY r.id ;
```

Comment: According to http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php the EXISTS statement is very inefficient. Does this mean this query is less efficient than UNION?

Comment: No, that statement: *"SQL Statements that use the SQL EXISTS Condition are very inefficient since the sub-query is RE-RUN for EVERY row in the outer query's table."* is false. Most DBMS implement `EXISTS` quite efficiently and do not rerun the subquery for every row of the external table. I would remove that site from my bookmarks.

Comment: You can certainly try all 3 versions of the query (UNION, EXISTS, LEFT JOIN) in your environment and test for efficiency.

Comment: The `UNION` seems to be the more efficient. Does this surprise you? https://gist.github.com/weppos/d552d978d604fbecd917

Comment: No really. the difference is very small. And there are several other ways to write the query. You could try `UNION` with `EXISTS` in the 2nd part (not INNER JOIN). Or using `IN` instead of `EXISTS` and possibly some other ways. But since it runs in about 30 ms, isn't is good enough?

Comment: Sure, I'm just trying to understand what is the best approach. Considering this is one of the most critical query and those tests where done on a very few records (whereas an user can have thousands of them), I'm taking the time to learn more about writing efficient queries.

Comment: I suggest then you do the tests with larger tables. Add some fake data, thousands or millions of rows (as many as you expect to have) and then experiment with the various queries.

Comment: @ypercube_: my test:  users(id int, n1 text ) -- 1k rows, records(id  int , n1 text , user_id FK) -- 1000k rows, memberships(id int , n1 text, user_id FK, record_id FK) -- 10000k rows -> time query are near the same, except the query with "group by" .